# DateAdd function in Sqlite server with column name as input

Tags: sqlite

**select DATE(`Orders`.`OrderDate`,'10 DAY') from Orders**. it will give the following result **"1996-07-14"**

When using column name directly instead of value in numeric it will give the empty result
**select DATE(`Orders`.`OrderDate`,'`Orders`.`OrderId` DAY') from Orders**.

What wrong with the above select query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try concatenating a string using the `OrderId` column:

```
SELECT DATE(Orders.OrderDate, '+' || Orders.OrderId || ' DAYS')
FROM Orders
```

You want a query of the form

```
SELECT DATE(Orders.OrderDate, '+7 DAYS') FROM Orders
```

and string concatenation will let you achieve that.